Stumped on a complex GROUP BY
Given the following query, how do I group by con_num and retrieve the lead_id with the MAX date_entered? I am using SQL Server 2012.
SELECT leads.id AS lead_id 
    , leads.date_entered 
    , so.con_num 
    , so.ord_date 
FROM crm.leads 
    INNER JOIN crm.contacts ON leads.contact_id = contacts.id 
    INNER JOIN crm.email_addr_bean_rel rel ON rel.bean_id = contacts.id 
    INNER JOIN crm.email_addresses email ON email.id = rel.email_address_id 
    INNER JOIN sales_order so ON so.bill_email = email.email_address OR so.dt_email = email.email_address 
WHERE rel.bean_module = 'contacts' AND so.ord_date >= leads.date_entered

For example, the current query returns (in part) the following two rows...



lead_id
date_entered
con_num
ord_date




1
2021-04-20
N0226091
2021-04-22


2
2021-04-21
N0226091
2021-04-22



The query should return one row per con_num that contains the latest lead_id along with its entered_date...



lead_id
date_entered
con_num
ord_date




2
2021-04-21
N0226091
2021-04-22



Thank you.

have you tried putting a MAX and GROUP BY there?

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result.

latest lead_id - does that mean highest lead_id?

@jarth, latest is based on the date_entered field.

Use ROW_NUMBER() window function to get each so.con_num's latest lead_id/date_entered row.
select lead_id, date_entered, con_num, ord_date
from
(
    SELECT leads.id AS lead_id 
        , leads.date_entered 
        , so.con_num 
        , so.ord_date
        , row_number() over (partition by so.con_num
                             order by leads.id desc, leads.date_entered desc) rn
    FROM crm.leads 
        INNER JOIN crm.contacts ON leads.contact_id = contacts.id 
        INNER JOIN crm.email_addr_bean_rel rel ON rel.bean_id = contacts.id 
        INNER JOIN crm.email_addresses email ON email.id = rel.email_address_id 
        INNER JOIN sales_order so ON so.bill_email = email.email_address OR so.dt_email = email.email_address 
    WHERE rel.bean_module = 'contacts' AND so.ord_date >= leads.date_entered
) dt
where rn = 1

